# how to execute .r files in windows

Tags: windows, r

Below is the code in a `.r` file. I want to execute this from a Windows command prompt, but how?

```
library(coda)
a <- read.coda("CODAchain1.txt","CODAindex.txt")
out <- capture.output(summary(a)) 
cat(out,file="out.txt",sep="\n",append=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a text file named `coda_scrp.r` and then at the command prompt type:

```
R CMD BATCH /<full-path>/coda_scrp.r
```

Jim Lemon is one of the R guru's that contribute on r-help. He does a lot of graphics stuff with base graphics and is a major contributor to the plotrix package. He also has a website for "Kickstarting R" and you can get more [details about running R scripts here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Lemon-kickstart/kr_scrpt.html):

Here's a link to a [well written set of instructions](http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/programming-in-r#Progr_run) that show the differences in using R CMD BATCH and Rscript:

And here is an answer on SO showing how to use a .bat file: [Start RScript without DOS box (on Windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332075/start-rscript-without-dos-box-on-windows)

Comment: No good reason. You would probably write a better answer. I just wrote that up because the first answer was wrong.